# Powershell how to convert from json to hashtable

Tags: powershell

I got a script that output the result(hashtable) to a json file then I'm trying to convert the json back to hashtable but I can't make it work

**CODE**

```
$jsonOutput = "$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\output.json"

$processStatus | ConvertTo-Json > $jsonOutput

$hashtable = @{}

(ConvertFrom-Json $jsonOutput).psobject.properties | Foreach { $hashtable[$_.Name] = $_.Value }
```

**ERROR**

ConvertFrom-Json : Invalid JSON primitive: C.
    $hashtable = @{}

```
(ConvertFrom-Json $jsonOutput).psobject.properties | Foreach { $hashtable[$_.Name] = $_.Value }
```

Comment: `$processStatus | ConvertTo-Json | Set-Content $jsonOutput` `(Get-Content $jsonOutput) | ConvertFrom-Json -AsHashTable` This switch was introduced in PowerShell 6.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The variable `$jsonOutput` contains the name of the file that contains the json. `ConvertFrom-Json` wants an actual json string, not the name of a json file.

Just pipe the contents of the file into `ConvertFrom-Json`:

```
(Get-Content $jsonOutput | ConvertFrom-Json).psobject.properties | Foreach { $hashtable[$_.Name] = $_.Value }
```